# How to change the color of red edit-polygon or purple snap-confirmation?

Tags: qgis, snapping

I'm having trouble seeing the purple or pink snapping confirmation when drawing a polygon because the temporary polygon is red (QGIS 2.0.1). Also the vertices in edit mode are also red. I looked through the options, but couldn't find a place to change those colors.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, now I found it: Options --> Digitize --> Rubberband --> Line color. Really makes editing easier making it a transparent white for digitizing old maps.